# Php symfony Fatal Error

Tags: php, symfony, pager

```
getNbResults()) : ?> getResults() as $offer) : ?> getMOVIE()->getTitle(); ?>  
while running this success page i am getting the following error: Fatal error: Call to a member  
function getTitle() on a non-object in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\Menakaa\TicketBounty\dev\apps\backend\modules\offer\templates\searchOfferSuccess.php on line 68
```

Comment: That means `$offer->getMovie()` does not return an object. Check your `Offer` object at method `getMovie` to see what can be wrong. You can also check with `var_dump($offer->getMovie())` and see what is returned - I assume Null. Then, just make a test before calling the method. `if ($offer->getMovie()) { echo $offer->getMovie()->getTitle(); }`

Answer (score 0):

Try to close `foreach` loop. at this time this loop is accepting only first line.